# Video website with suggestion/recommendation feature

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, recommendation-engine

i have been assigned on making a simple **video lecture website** with a **recommendation feature** for students in  my place. I have little knowledge on html,css,java & php since i only learnt through YouTube. My main concerns are what should i do first or next and as for recommendation feature, they wanted to use a **'knowledge tree' concept**.

*E.g. when a student plays video **topic V**, then the recommended videos will be either **video topic X and video topic Z**. These recommended videos are based on **lecturer's suggestion**.*

As for the recommendation feature part, the only idea came into my mind is using the (If Else) statement for each video but not sure in what language or where to put the algorithm. Lastly, is it a good practice to store video in mysql database?

Comment: Recommendation engines are the topic of PhD-level research, just warning you.

Comment: thank you for notifying me. for this case, what i meant on "recommendation" is not exactly like YouTube which i know its very complex and and it has its own intelligence in it . What i'm trying to do is that to play a video topic V and also display the specific suggested video names e.g. when it plays video X, the suggested video will be video M, Video N or video P.

Answer (score 0):

You can use video names to show similar videos below active one or you can manualy give each video a code or name and show every video that has that code or name below active one.

Comment: Do i have to make each page for each video in order to have the suggestion feature specifically for that particular video or is it possible only using one display video page?

Comment: No it's not proffesional at all.use just one page with all things you want be on page then you can disable or enable some features for specific videos